# Issue connecting to Compute Engine after updating VPC subnet - Cloud IAP to TCP netblock to SSH - firewall rule?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-vpc, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

I created a VPC subnet to enable dual stack IPv4 and IPv6

When I try to SSH to my Compute engine, I get a message

> "Please consider adding a firewall rule to allow ingress from the Cloud IAP for TCP forwarding netblock to the SSH port of your machine to start using Cloud IAP for TCP forwarding for better performance"

I went to [this article](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/tutorial-gce) and did Step 5: Set up IAP.

**Problem**:

> Source IP ranges (press Enter after you paste each value in the box):
> 130.211.0.0/22
> 35.191.0.0/16

What are these numbers? Do I need to add AS-IS ? ***I have no clue hmmm***

When creating subnet I specified **IPv4 range** like 1#2.#9.0.0/12

Do I need to update IP in Step 5?

[image]

**Edit firewall rule button takes me to**

[image]

**Please can you give solution with steps**

Thank you

EDIT:

I continued looking around [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding).

[image]

After assigning roles ---> Select a role Select Cloud IAP > IAP-Secured Tunnel User., Select a role Select Compute Engine > Compute Instance Admin (v1) ***I am now getting***:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried wihout Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy?

Comment: I created a new machine and this time I enabled dual stack (using this new subnet). I no longer have any issue

Comment: @KrisSwat Are you going to post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating new compute engine using VPC Subnet (that I wanted to use for existing VM).

Selected  dual stack this time

opened ICMP from firewall to enable "ping"

I did get a warning, when I opened only 22 , 3389. So I opened tcp (will apply rule again)

[image]